# Blocking sender domain from maillog

Tags: postfix, spam, scripting

In our mail server we are taking lots of hits. In the maillog there are lots of these:

```
Apr 23 04:35:13 mail1 postfix/smtpd[31700]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[119.153.14.231]: 554 <bob@domainname.net>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; from=<hareme.com@shareme.com> to=<bob@domainname.net> proto=ESMTP helo=<localhost>
```

I have a script which searches for the IPs and block those. I'm having a problem when I IP block the RCPT IP's. Instead I want to block the senders domain, like in this example: shareme.com. What should I modify in my script to do this?

```
#!/bin/bash
IPT=/sbin/iptables
LIMIT=10
cd /admin
# first get one minute of log
grep "`date +"%b %d %H:%M:" --date="1 minutes ago"`" /var/log/maillog > minutelog
# now extract the rejected attempts, sort and count uniq ip
cat minutelog | grep "reject:" | cut -d" " -f10 | cut -d"[" -f2 | cut -d"]" -f 1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' > tmp1
# for each line in result
while read line
do
MYCOUNT=`echo $line | cut -d" " -f1`
MYIP=`echo $line | cut -d" " -f2`
if [ $MYCOUNT -lt $LIMIT ] ;
then
echo $MYIP is ok: $MYCOUNT attempts
else
echo blocking the spammer at $MYIP with $MYCOUNT attempts
$IPT -I INPUT -i eth0 --proto tcp -s $MYIP --destination-port 25 -j DROP
echo $MYIP >> blocked.smtp
fi
done < tmp1
rm -f minutelog
rm -f tmp1
```

Comment: Deleted, didn't notice count in script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to block by SMTP sender domain using only IP filter because e-mail with given domain could originate from any IP. Moreover it is dangerous to block by sender domain at all because anyone could spoof sender e-mail and send multiple messages with something like somebody@google.com and your script will happily block all traffic from gmail.

To solve your problem I recommend checking section "Measures against clients that make too many connections" in http://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html

Answer (score 1):

It's better to try Fail2ban: http://www.fail2ban.org/

Fail2ban scans log files like /var/log/pwdfail or /var/log/apache/error_log and bans IP that makes too many password failures. It updates firewall rules to reject the IP address.